# count is wrong for author related book why and how to solve?

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I work on SQL Server 2012 and I face an issue: count is wrong for book s related to author. Why is count for books related to author is wrong for author Ahmed?

When count author ahmed I get an incorrect result although it has related records in the books table as 3 and bookupdate 3 then all will be 6.

How to solve that please?

```
create table #books  
(  
    BookId int,  
    BookName nvarchar(200),  
    AuthorId  int  
)  

create table #booksUpdate  
(  
    BookId int,  
    BookName nvarchar(200),  
    AuthorId  int  
)  

insert into #booksUpdate  
values (119, 'matlab', 1), (120, '3dmax', 1), (121, 'c', 1)  

create table #Authors  
(  
    AuthorId int,  
    AuthorName nvarchar(200)  
)  

insert into #Authors  
values  (1, 'Ahmed'), (2, 'Mohamed'), (3, 'Eslam')  

insert into #books  
values (122, 'c#', 1), (233, 'Java', 1), 
       (555, 'c++', 1), (666, 'photoshop', 2),  
       (777, 'asp.net', 2), (888, 'python', 2)  
  
select 
    a.authorName, 
    count(b.BookName) as countBooks, 
    count(bu.BookName) as countBooksUpdate,
    (count(bu.BookName) + count(b.BookName)) as Total 
from 
    #Authors a   
left join 
    #books b on a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId  
left join 
    #booksUpdate bu on a.AuthorId = bu.AuthorId  
group by 
    a.authorName
```

Output:

```
authorName  countBooks  countBooksUpdate    Total  
--------------------------------------------------
Ahmed            9              9             18  
Eslam            0              0              0  
Mohamed          3              0              3
```

Result is wrong for author `Ahmed`.

It should be

```
authorName  countBooks  countBooksUpdate    Total 
-------------------------------------------------
Ahmed            3                 3          6
```

How to fix query to return the correct result?

Expected result is

```
authorName  countBooks  countBooksUpdate    Total  
-------------------------------------------------
Ahmed           3             3                6  
Eslam           0             0                0  
Mohamed         3             0                3
```

Comment: Why are you posting similar questions on different forums and not accepting answers? I see [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/70395/how-to-select-statment-to-data-dividing-to-3-parts.html) and [this other one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/74231/how-to-count-all-books-related-to-all-authors.html) on Microsoft Q&A.

Comment: Aside: Typically it makes more sense to `group by AuthorId` rather than `AuthorName`. That keeps multiple authors with the same name separate and, in some cases, may eliminate the need to join to the `Authors` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.  It was missing the join on BookId between #books and #booksUpdate

```
select a.authorName,count(b.BookName) as countBooks,
                    count(bu.BookName) as countBooksUpdate,
                   (count(bu.BookName) + count(b.BookName)) as Total
from #Authors a   
     left join #books b on a.AuthorId=b.AuthorId  
     left join #booksUpdate bu on a.AuthorId=bu.AuthorId  
                                  and b.BookId=bu.BookId
group by a.authorName;
```

Results

```
authorName  countBooks  countBooksUpdate    Total
Ahmed       3           0                   3
Eslam       0           0                   0 
Mohamed     3           0                   3
```

The BookId's in the #booksUpdate table do not match any in the #books table.  Without the join on BookId the query is performing a cross join.

Suppose the 3 rows in #booksUpdate were changed to match 3 rows for Ahmed.  Here I'm changing the data posted in the question.

```
drop table if exists #booksUpdate;
go
create table #booksUpdate  
(  
BookId int,  
BookName nvarchar(200),  
AuthorId  int  
)  
insert into #booksUpdate  
values  
(122,'matlab',1),  
(233,'3dmax',1),  
(555,'c',1)
```

Then the result would be as follows:

```
authorName  countBooks  countBooksUpdate    Total
Ahmed       3           3                   6
Eslam       0           0                   0
Mohamed     3           0                   3
```

Comment: It's true the query returns 0 for booksupdate count because the join on BookId yields no rows.  That's the data.  If there were rows which happened to match on the appropriate keys then the count would be positive.